# Automate, Start & Stop a specific service instance in TIBCO administrator using java (backend)

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

Am new (and am from not IT background) to this TIBCO community and need your immediate help in finding out a quick resolution to my below requirement .

I need to automate Start and Stop activity on a specific service instance in TIBCO Administrator(TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks 5.13.0) using java .kindly explain me in layman terms.

1. What all the information i need in order to perform this activity?
2. This is what i need to automate in TIBCO Adminstrator in backend.
   a. start/stop  Service instance 
   b. confirm if the service instance is started/stopped.

Thanks in advance.

### TIBCO Version used:

TIBCO Administrator

Version Information

TIBCO Administrator:    5.10.0_V19
Tomcat: 7.0.62.0
TIBCO Repository:   5.10.0_V18
JRE:    1.8.0_191
TRA:    5.10.0_V19
TIBCO Rendezvous (RV):  8.4.5
TIBCO Hawk: 5.2.0.V21

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find out if service is running or not on machine where it is deployed. normally you may use ps -eaf|grep  then you will get the application.tra path with PID in it... it means your service is up and running..if now output is there then it means application/service is in stopped state.

though you may also create tibco hawk rule bases (tibco monitoring tool) for your application which will send you the alert if service would be in start/stop state.
Let me know if you need more help on it.
--Manoj

Comment: thanks for the reply !! but i need to automate start and stop activity, not just finding the status of it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start and stop, you can do this easily by using AppManage command.

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/runtime_agent/5.7.4-june-2012/doc/pdf/tib_TRA_script_deploy_usr/tib_TRA_script_deploy_usr.pdf), but here is the general syntax:

```
AppManage -start –domain <DomainName>  -user admin -pw xxxxx   -app "Folder/Path/to/App/Appname" -service "Process Archive.par" -binding "Process Archive
```

Some parameters are optional, again, please refer to the documentation for details.

As @Manoj pointed out, you need to know which applications are stopped before you can fire a start command. For that, you can do the ps -ef grep command in Unix.

In summary, you can achieve the entire thing using just Unix commands. All you have to do is call these Unix commands in your Java code and pass the relevant variables.

Steps:

1. `ps -ef | grep appname`

This will give you where the app is started or not (no result will means not started).

2. `AppManage -start –domain <DomainName>  -user admin -pw xxxxx   -app "Folder/Path/to/App/Appname" -service "Process Archive.par" -binding "Process Archive`

This will start the application.

3. `AppManage -start –domain <DomainName>  -user admin -pw xxxxx   -app "Folder/Path/to/App/Appname" -service "Process Archive.par" -binding "Process Archive`

This will stop the application.